# Create local copy of a list to be able to change elements only in new list - vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

This is probably a really basic question - but I have a list of items (custom objects) being passed from one winform (.net 3.5) to another.  I want to create a local list to store changes that only get persisted if the user clicks save.  Currently if the user clicks cancel - the changes are still applied in the first form because I assume the objects are reference type.

I have the save working as it calls a service layer to do the save and then refreshes the other form - but not the cancel.

How do I create a new list from the first list where the objects act independently to the other list? (Hopefully this makes sense :))

Otherwise on cancel I'm going to have to rollback the changes which seems a less efficient way of handling the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Creating a deep copy of the list isn't exactly an efficient way either.  Do consider applying the changes only after a 'save' confirmation.  A delegate can do wonders.

Comment: The list that I'm working with is only a subset of "selected data" and the screen behaviour is such that they wouldn't be likely to perform this action on a large bulk number of items.  But thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would then have to clone all the entities in the list and add them to a new list. 
Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp) which has some info on cloning.

Comment: Thanks so much - ended up adding a copy function to my entity which achieved what I needed to :)